How to expose custom application in Kubeflow via Istio?
I want to publish some services via Istio in the Kubeflow Kubernetes cluster, for example, prometheus.mydomain.examle.com or mlflow.mydomain.examle.com. While my kubeflow central dashboard is available by mydomain.examle.com
Now, everything seems to be working, but if you go to one of the URLs, then the next one will not open. In short, if you use a private tab, the first URL requested is always opened. Why and how to fix it?
---
# https://github.com/adeo/dp--deploy-kubeflow/blob/v1.7-branch/common/oidc-authservice/base/envoy-filter.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: metrics
  namespace: metrics
spec:
  gateways:
  - metrics-gateway
  hosts:
  - 'prometheus.mydomain.examle.com'
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.metrics.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 9090

---
# https://github.com/adeo/dp--deploy-kubeflow/blob/v1.7-branch/common/oidc-authservice/base/envoy-filter.yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: metrics-gateway
  namespace: metrics
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - 'prometheus.mydomain.examle.com'
    port:
      name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: tls
      mode: SIMPLE

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: authn-filter
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    # https://github.com/adeo/dp--deploy-prometheus/blob/master/helm/values/istio-kubeflow-resources
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: mlflow.ml.data.lmru.tech:443
      patch:
          operation: MERGE
          value:
            typed_per_filter_config:
              envoy.filters.http.ext_authz:
                '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
                disabled: true
    # https://github.com/adeo/dp--deploy-prometheus/blob/master/helm/values/istio-kubeflow-resources
    - applyTo: VIRTUAL_HOST
      match:
        routeConfiguration:
          vhost:
            name: prometheus.mydomain.examle.com:443
      patch:
          operation: MERGE
          value:
            typed_per_filter_config:
              envoy.filters.http.ext_authz:
                '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthzPerRoute
                disabled: true
    - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
      patch:
        # For some reason, INSERT_FIRST doesn't work
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          # See: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.0/configuration/http/http_filters/ext_authz_filter#config-http-filters-ext-authz
          name: "envoy.filters.http.ext_authz"
          typed_config:
            '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.ext_authz.v3.ExtAuthz
            http_service:
              server_uri:
                uri: http://$(AUTHSERVICE_SERVICE).$(AUTHSERVICE_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
                cluster: outbound|8080||$(AUTHSERVICE_SERVICE).$(AUTHSERVICE_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
                timeout: 10s
              authorization_request:
                allowed_headers:
                  patterns:
                    # XXX: MUST be lowercase!
                    - exact: "authorization"
                    - exact: "cookie"
                    - exact: "x-auth-token"
              authorization_response:
                allowed_upstream_headers:
                  patterns:
                    - exact: "kubeflow-userid"

I created my own Gateway and VirtualService for each endpoint, and also added an exception for authentication via oidc-authservice to the Envoy Filter authn-filter
